# Distributed semaphore on multiply services by curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed, apache-curator

I'm new to zookeeper and curator.

I want to use zookeeper and curator to control our services. The situation is that our services are based on hardware devices, so each device as a provider could **only run one task at one time**. As we have many devices, I design to use curator's semaphore to count the whole number, but how to find the exactly devices is a problem. Because **one job might need many devices at one time** to run (devices are independent), and the number can not be defined, so **each time we need to lock N devices and to send the task info**

e.g.As I thought, we register device as EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL in curator:

```
/root/services/
              /devices00000001
              /devices00000002
              ...
```

whether we use a lock on each device or use a flag in znode's data, it will cost us a lot of time to find the available devices. So I wander if there are some common solutions to these problems? Maybe I should not use zookeeper but other software?

Comment: Based on Randgalt's answer, I finally use a semaphere to control the number and each device has its own locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an InterProcessMutex for each device - I assume each device has some unique ID. Something like:

```
String path = ZKPaths.makePath("/some/base/path", deviceId);
InterProcessMutex lock = new InterProcessMutex(curator, path);
if ( lock.acquire(max, unit) ) {
    try {
        DO WORK HERE
    } finally {
        lock.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use mutex for each device, for example,when one job need 100 devices,and we have 1000 devices, I have to iterate over the whole path, from 1-1000, try to lock 100 available devices. Which I don't think it's efficient enough. However, as I'm not familiar with zookeeper, I just wander if there are already existing solutions, I'm not sure there is an answer.

Comment: Given your description it's hard to answer conclusively. You can easily get all the outstanding locks (note: it's only a rough estimate because of concurrency issues) by calling getChildren() on the parent path of the all the locks.

Comment: oh，I think I knew what you mean. And checking all locks doesn't cost much. Thank you for your answer. 